# Losing Explicit Binding of the `this` Keyword

Tags: javascript, this

What is an example/scenario of how the `this` keyword can lose its explicit binding and be paved over with the default binding? Here's an example code snippet which explicitly binds the `this` keyword to an object by using the `call` method. What theoretical additions to this code can change the value of `this`? What specific concerns are we protecting our code from when hard binding the `this` keyword?

```
function foo(){
  console.log(this.bar); // outputs: 9
}

var obj = {
  bar: 9
};

foo.call(obj);
```

Comment: The value of `this` depends on *how* the function is *called*. There are multiple ways to call a function, and hence multiple ways how `this` gets its value. This is all well explained in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . A function can be explicitly bound via `.bind()`, in which case the value of `this` can never be changed again.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, but not really what I was asking.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not asking about the multiple ways of how `this` gets its value. Rather I'm asking specifically about the "safety" of defining and retaining the value of the `this` keyword, when using the `call` method. My question pertains to the circumstances in when that value will get replaced due to one of the many rules the `this` keyword has.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then in case where the function is already bound to a specific `this` value via `.bind`, `.call(obj)` won't have any effect (i.e. `this` would not be set to `obj`).

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. If you'd do something like this: `var otherObj = {bar: 8}; var foo = foo.bind(otherObj);`. That would change the value of `this`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there's no "explicit" binding of `this`. The value of `this` is determined whenever a function is invoked based on the nature of the invocation. It has nothing to do with the circumstances of the function's "birth".

When a function is called after having its reference discovered via an object property lookup, as in:

```
obj.someFunction();
```

then the object reference involved (`obj`, above) will be the value of `this` in that particular invocation of the function. However, the function reference can easily be copied to another object:

```
var otherObj = { someFunction: obj.someFunction };
otherObj.someFunction();
```

Now the value of `this` (in that particular invocation) will be a reference to `otherObj`, not `obj`.

If the reference to the function is copied to a plain variable:

```
var func = obj.someFunction;

func();
```

the value of `this` in *that* invocation will be a reference to `window`, or `undefined` if the code happens to be in a "strict" context.

Through all this, note that the fact that the function may originally have been declared as a property value in an object literal has *nothing* to do with what ends up being the value of `this` in an invocation.

A way to create an explicit "binding" is to take advantage of the built-in `.call()` or `.apply()` methods available to every function instance:

```
function whatever() { /* ... */ }

var objWhatever = function() {
  whatever.call(obj);
};
```

That setup explicitly forces a reference to `obj` to be used as the value of `this` in an invocation of function `whatever()`.  You can also use the built-in (in modern environments) `.bind()` function to create such a "bound" function:

```
var objWhatever = whatever.bind(obj);
```

I personally would hesitate to call that a "bound" function, because under the covers it's just an explicit call via `.call()`, but terminology is not something I worry about *too* much. :)

Comment: "In general there's no "explicit" binding of this." Can you elaborate more on that point please? What do you mean?

Comment: @shmuli just that - unlike in languages like Java, C++, or C#, there is no intrinsic relation ship between any particular function and any particular object.

Comment: I guess you're saying that it's not really "explicit" in the first place if that relationship can be lost. Yes?

Comment: @shmuli right - when you create a function with the `function` keyword in an expression, the result is just a simple object reference (to the new function).  The fact that the reference is assigned to an object property really has no long-term importance.

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy mentioned the value of `this`, or the context depends on how the function is called, this article [Understanding Scope and Context in Javascript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) does a good job of explaining how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code overrides the "explicit" binding, and the `this` keyword now returns `8`, resulting from the "implicit" binding created by the `otherObj` object. The function is invoked within that object's space.

```
var otherObj = {
  foo: foo,
  bar: 8
};
otherObj.foo();
```

Further add this code, and since the function is invoked in the global space without any decoration, the "implicit" binding is overridden by the "default" binding which returns the global `bar` variable, resulting with `7`.

```
var secondObj = otherObj.foo;
var bar = 7;
secondObj();
```

Adding this code before the function is invoked with the `call` method, will result with locking the `this` keyword onto the `secondObj` object - and resulting with the output of `6`.

```
var thirdObj = {
  bar: 6
};

var foo = foo.bind(thirdObj);
```